# T/F: If $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that AB=$I_n$, then $A$ and $B$ are square matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my book (Linear Algebra by Steven Andrilli 4th ed.) There is a true/false question in the chapter 2 review that's all about "systems of linear equations." The question asks:

T/F: If $A$ and $B$ are matrices such that AB=$I_n$, then $A$ and $B$ are square matrices.

I said that this was true. The correct answer according to the book is False.

If $A$ is $m$x$n$ non-square matrix and $B$ is $n$x$p$ square matrix, then $A$*$B$ is an $m$x$p$ matrix. I don't understand how it can be square if $A$ or $B$ is non square.

Comment: Can you not simply have that $B$ is $n \times m$?

Comment: the dimension of the product has to be $n\times n$, $A,B$ could be anything as long as they can be multiplied and give the required dimension when multiplied.

Comment: oh never mind. I don't know why I had such a hard time with this, it's obviously false. ha. thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why it is false. $B = A^{-1}$. But, to calculate inverse, we need the determinant which is only defined for square matrices. So, the matrices have to be square matrices.

Comment: @user230452 If $AB=I_n$, we don't necessarily have $B=A^{-1}$. In fact, this will only hold if $A$ and $B$ are square matrices.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: not exactly. You use the fact that the product is a square matrix, but don't use the fact it is a particular square matrix, namely the identity. This additional condition *may* force $A$ and $B$ to be squared. It is actually not the case (see my answer).

Comment: @Taladris Pick any row vector as a finite sequence of distinct primes, means their gcd is 1 therefore there exists a column vector of "same length" with integers such that when we multiply the two vectors together we get $I_1$ :)

Comment: If you want to know more about such matrices, you should look up left/right/generalized/pseudo-inverses.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the example, A=$\begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\\end{matrix}$ and B=$\begin{matrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\\\end{matrix}$.

Then, $AB=1$, which is the (square) identity matrix $I_1$. However, $A$ and $B$ were not square. (Always best to think of the simplest counter examples :) )

**Edit:** You also asked,

> If $A$ is $m \times n$ non-square matrix and $B$ is $n \times p$ square matrix, then $A*B$ is an $m \times p$ matrix. I don't understand how it can be square if $A$ or $B$ is non square.

As one comment also says above, $A$ and $B$ don't have to be square this way. For example, if $A$ is an $m \times n$ non-square matrix, and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix so also non-square, then $AB$ will be a $m \times m$ matrix. Therefore we get a square product out of non-square matrices.

Comment: This is confusing me. Suppose, you were given $A$ and asked to compute $A^{-1}$, how would you arrive at B ?

Comment: If $A$ is not square, it does not have an inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ (a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant (only defined for square matrices) is non-zero). So you cannot arrive at $B$ this way

Comment: @user230452 note, in fact, that there are many possible $B$s that satisfy $AB = I_1$.  In particular, we can take 
$$B = \pmatrix{1\\t}$$
for any $t \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $AB=I_n$ means that $A$ has $n$ rows, $B$ has $n$ columns and the number of columns of $A$ is the same as the number of rows of $B$, say $m$.

Also, $I_n$ is the matrix of an injective (resp. surjective) linear application, so $A$ (resp. $B$) is also the matrix of an injective (resp. surjective) of a linear apllication. This implies that $n \leqslant m$. I think we cannot say much more from the given condition.

The condition is however not enough to affirm that $A$ and $B$ must be square. Indeed, here is a counter-example:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, whose product is $I_2$.

Comment: This is probably off the topic of my original question, but I was wondering how it is that $I_n$ is the matrix of an "injective" linear application. I think, if I remember correctly, that injectivity is when for every $a,b$ $f(a) = f(b)$ implies that $a=b$. But I don't understand what this has to do with that.

Comment: @JosiahBlaisdell This might come a bit later in your learning of linear algebra. Matrices represent linear maps, and the dimension of the kernel of the map comes to the number of rows in the matrix that are linearly dependent. Therefore, the kernel is 0 (dimensional) when all rows are linearly independent (which is the case for $I_n$), and kernel of a map being zero means it is injective (proving this last statement is a popular exercise of algebra courses).